# How to put several formulas outside of a plot (top) using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have problems using `annotation_custom`.

Here is the dataset:

```
   DOSE PROD     pH
1     0   CL 4.3550
2     0   CO 4.3250
3     0   CZ 4.1475
4     0   PF 4.2300
5     0   RP 4.1225
6    25   CL 4.3420
7    25   CO 4.3520
8    25   CZ 4.7840
9    25   PF 4.2640
10   25   RP 4.3325
11   50   CL 4.6220
12   50   CO 4.4760
13   50   CZ 5.2580
14   50   PF 4.2020
15   50   RP 4.2040
16   75   CL 4.4100
17   75   CO 4.6080
18   75   CZ 6.1180
19   75   PF 4.2700
20   75   RP 4.1900
21  100   CL 4.7700
22  100   CO 4.9280
23  100   CZ 6.4550
24  100   PF 4.2320
25  100   RP 4.2040
```

this is my code for the plot :

```
sp1 <- 
  ggplot(ab, aes(x=DOSE, y=pH, Groups=PROD)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=PROD, colour=PROD, fill=PROD), size=4) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Residuos\nAgroindustriais", 
                  breaks=levels(dados$PROD),
                  labels=c(expression(CL), expression(CO), expression(CZ), expression(RP[P20]),
                           expression(RP[P100])),
                  values=c("black","black","black","black","black")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Residuos\nAgroindustriais", 
                breaks=levels(dados$PROD),       
                labels=c(expression(CL), expression(CO), expression(CZ), expression(RP[P20]),
                         expression(RP[P100])), 
                values=c("black","grey","grey80","grey50","white")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="Residuos\nAgroindustriais", 
                 breaks=levels(dados$PROD),             
                 labels=c(expression(CL), expression(CO), expression(CZ), expression(RP[P20]),
                          expression(RP[P100])), 
                 values=c(21:25) )+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Residuos\nAgroindustriais", 
                    breaks=levels(dados$PROD),                     
                    labels=c(expression(CL), expression(CO), expression(CZ), expression(RP[P20]),
                             expression(RP[P100])),
                    values=c(1:5)) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x)(4.15+0.024*x), geom="line", aes(linetype="CZ"), size=1) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x)(4.31+0.003*x), geom="line", aes(linetype="CL"), size=1)+stat_function(fun=function(x)(4.23+0.006*x), geom="line", aes(linetype="CO"), size=1)+stat_function(fun=function(x)(4.21+0*x), geom="line", aes(linetype="RP"), size=1)+stat_function(fun=function(x)(4.24+0*x), geom="line", aes(linetype="PF"), size=1)+
  xlab("") + 
  ylab(expression(bold("pH"~ (CaCl[2]))))+theme_bw() +                                                                 
  geom_text(x=40, y=5.6,parse=TRUE, label="RP==4.21", family="Times New Roman",
        colour="black", hjust=0.5, size=4)+
  geom_text(x=40, y=5.3,parse=TRUE, label="RP==4.24", family="Times New Roman", 
        colour="black", hjust=0.5,size=4)+    
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold", family="Times New Roman"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=15,face="bold",family="Times New Roman"),
    axis.text=element_text(size=15,face="bold",family="Times New Roman"),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=15,family="Times New Roman"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),  
    axis.line=element_line(colour="black"),
    legend.position="none") +
  annotation_custom(expression(textGrob("CZ=4.15+0.024*X," ~ R^{2}==0.95), 
                           xmin = 40, xmax =40 , ymin = 6.2, ymax=6.2) +
                  annotation_custom(textGrob(expression("CO=4.23+0.006*X,"~R^{2}==0.63),
                                             xmin = 40, xmax =40 , ymin =6.7, ymax=6.7)+
                                      annotation_custom(textGrob(expression("CL=4.31+0.003*X"~R^{2}==0.25)),
                                                        xmin = 40, xmax =40 , ymin = 6.6, ymax =6.6 )
```

I've tried first with 3 formulas, but I can't get them out of the plot, it always stays inside. I've tried using `arrangeGrob()` also but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't you have missing closing brackets `)` in `annotation_custom`?

Comment: I tried a lot of things in the process, probably when i copied the code, some of the brackets could be missing, but when i´ve tried the code before didn´t work. Thank you for modifying the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

exprGrob <- function(..., parse=TRUE, spacing=unit(0.5,"line")){

  labs <- list(...)
  if(parse) labs <- lapply(labs, function(x)parse(text=x))
  labs <- lapply(labs, textGrob, 
                 gp=gpar(fontface="bold",fontfamily="Times"))

  widths <- do.call(unit.c, lapply(labs, grobWidth))
  heights <- do.call(unit.c, lapply(labs, grobHeight))
  g <- gtable_matrix(name = "expr", 
                     grobs = matrix(labs, ncol=1, nrow=length(labs)), 
                     widths = max(widths), heights = heights+spacing)

  g
}

title <- exprGrob("alpha", "beta")

g <- gtable_add_grob(ggplotGrob(qplot(1,1)), list(title), 
                     t = 1, l = 4)
g$heights[[1]] <- sum(title$heights)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I have one last question, how to i change the font of the texts produced ? thank you

Comment: i don't know what you mean, for size/colour have a look at `?textGrob`, for font families `?plotmath`

Comment: I found the parameters, but i dont know where to put it in the code to express the changes ... i would like to set it like this : gp=gpar(fontsize = 10, fontface = "bold",font="Times")... thank you very much